Arithmetic properties of exceptional moduli
For a fundamental discriminant $d$, let $\chi_d = \left(\frac{d}{\cdot} \right)$ be the quadratic character associated with the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Consider the associated Dirichlet $L$-function given by
$$\displaystyle L(s, \chi_d) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_d(n)}{n^s}$$
for $\Re(s) > 1$, and can of course be analytically continued to a holomorphic function on the complex plane.
A famous problem in analytic number theory concerns so-called Landau-Siegel zeroes, namely a real zero $\beta_d$ of $L(s, \chi_d)$ which cannot provably fall into the `standard' zero-free region. In particular, such zeroes should not exist, and their existence are in a sense orthogonal to the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis (i.e., if GRH is true, then not only do such zeroes not exist, but there are no non-trivial real zeroes of $L(s,\chi_d)$ at all).
For concreteness, define a modulu $q$ to be $\delta$-exceptional if there exists $1 - \beta_q \geq |q|^{-\delta}$ such that $L(\beta_q, \chi_q) = 0$.
It is known such exceptional moduli must be very rare: for example, for any two moduli $q_1, q_2$ (not necessarily exceptional) and real zeroes $\beta_{q_1}, \beta_{q_2}$ we have Landau's estimate, giving
$$\displaystyle \min\{\beta_{q_1}, \beta_{q_2}\} < 1 - \frac{B}{\log |q_1 q_2|}$$
where $B$ is an effectively computable constant. If we assume $|q_1| < |q_2|$ and both $q_1, q_2$ are exceptional with $\beta_{q_2} > \beta_{q_1}$, then $q_2$ is forced to be extremely large compared to $q_1$. This gives an ``archimedean repulsion principle" for Landau-Siegel zeroes.
I am asking about arithmetic relations between potential exceptional moduli $q_1, q_2$. For example, is it possible that $\gcd(q_1, q_2)$ is very large (relative to say $\min\{q_1, q_2\}$)?
Also, for a single exceptional modulus $q$, can one say anything about the roughness or smoothness of $q$? That is, is it possible for $q$ to be very smooth (in particular, has many prime factors)?

"which cannot provably fall into the `standard' zero-free region" ????

I gave a more precise definition of what kind of zero I am looking at later in the post.
